# Is it possible to enable hover in the simulator?

Tags: codenameone

I was thinking about creating sort of animated screenshots of my app running in the simulator and created some code which is able to record an animated GIF image where I am also able to draw the current pointer as a gloved hand on top.
Then I realised it woud be much better if the pointer was shown even if it is not down.
Therefore - is it possible to enable hover in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

We have the ability to show it in the JavaSE port but that isn't exposed in the simulator. If you change the compile path to the project you can use:

```
JavaSEPort.setInvokePointerHover(true);
```